# .htaccess 300 handling

Tags: .htaccess, multiple-choice

I have a page mypage.html which I need to change to mypage.php. If I upload mypage.php and remove mypage.html, I get a 300 Multiple Choice error from Apache.

Can I set the htaccess to check if a .php verion of a page is available before it shows an error?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely you can. same Rewrite rules apply, just a different rule.

> RewriteBase /
>
> ErrorDocument 300 /error.php

You can change the error.php to whatever you want. Just have to ensure that you keep the relative paths the same. IE:

> / = root path /error/ = root path/error

Probably not the answer your looking for, but may give you a start.